# How to initialise class variable in unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a class which has a few functions and I am writing unittest for `delete` function in the class but I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'self', 'test1', 'test_id', and 'test_buckets'
```

```html
class TestEntry:
   

    def __init__(self, test1, test_id, test_buckets):
        self.test1 = test
        self.test_id = test_id
        self.test_buckets(buckets)


    def delete(self):
        if self.test_id in self.test1.entries:
            del self.test1.entries[self.test_id]
        return valve_of.groupdel(test_id=self.test_id)




class TestValveEntry(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_delete(self):
        newentry = TestEntry()
        addflow = newentry.add()
        delete_entry = newentry.delete(addflow)
        self.assertEqual(delete_entry, None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly answers the question. You have not provided the needed arguments to initialize your class.

```
def __init__(self, test1, test_id, test_buckets)
```

demands `test1, test_id, test_buckets` as arguments. But you are calling

```
newentry = TestEntry()
```

with no arguments.

Either give default values for your arguments like

```
def __init__(self, test1=None, test_id=None, test_buckets=None)
```

or pass proper arguments to the constructor.,